# Blackberry input field that mimics the input field of Android

Tags: blackberry, user-input, textinput

I'm trying to make a login screen for Blackberry with input fields for username and password that look like the the editText field of android. Basically, there should be a well defined background and default prompt text in a different color when no text has been input. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a default field provided by blackberry. I'm currently using an `EditField` and a `PasswordEditField` with `BorderFactory` to provide the demarcation. Is anyone aware of such libraries or some other open source efforts by someone to do so? Please point me to any tutorial, etc too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write your own custom field which extends EditField.

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Create_a_custom_field_508117_11.jsp

My suggestions are:

1. Override the `Field.paint()` method to place the label inside the text box (rather than to the left of it which is the default behaviour). This is where your instruction to the user can go, ie the 'Username' or 'Password' text.
2. Override the `Field.onFocus()` method to remove the instruction from the text box. Conversely override the `Field.onUnfocus()` method to add it back in if the user moves to another text box without entering any text.

Comment: Thanks man...I've written my own already, though. But I've done almost exactly as you've described so your answer is accepted :)